# How do I use a wildcard in a to read files from a directory with Node.js

Tags: file, wildcard

I need to read files from a directory with Node.js, The file names will all be some .json  How do I use a wildcard for the  portion of the file name in node.js?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`glob` npm](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) for using wildcard file name pattern matching

```
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional
glob("DIR_PATH/*.json", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // er is an error object or null.
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I was really stuck trying to figure it out.

Comment: Good answer. This is asynchronous though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob sync` when you wants to get list of files in single call synchronously.

```
  var glob = require("glob").sync;
  logfileNames = await glob("./logs/*.log");
```